# redux action returns undefined to the view

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I created simple login form and it works fine. I want to return the error message when API call fails (Login Fails).

Login.js file of the view

```
async  handleSubmit(event) {
    let userLoginObject = {
      login: this.state.username,
      password: this.state.password,
    }
    if (!isEmptyOrNull(this.state.username) &&
      !isEmptyOrNull(this.state.password)) {
      let resp = await this.props.onUserLogin(userLoginObject)
      console.log("resp",resp) // this shows 'undefined'
      this.setState({ formError: resp }); //Im trying to set state to the formError
    }
}
```

action file

```
export const onUserLogin = (userLoginData) => async (dispatch) => {
  const loginResponse = await doUserLogin(userLoginData)
  dispatch({
    type: ACTION_LOGIN,
    data: loginResponse,
  })
  if (loginResponse.token) {
      history.push('/investments')
  }
  else {
    console.log("error",loginResponse.error) // this shows the error message
    return loginResponse
  }
}
```

After failed  login attempt my console is like this

```
resp undefined
token:1 POST http://localhost:8000/token 400 (Bad Request)
authActions.js:52 error invalid credentials
```

It shows `undefined` even when I returned just a string inside the action.

What is wrong here ? How can I return the error message when API call fails.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that you're using `async/await`, but then only handling the case when the `doUserLogin` is successful. Remember that `async/await` is basically just sugar over promises.

Try this:

```
const loginResponse;
try {
  loginResponse = await doUserLogin(userLoginData)

  dispatch({
    type: ACTION_LOGIN,
    data: loginResponse,
  })

  if (loginResponse.token) {
    history.push('/investments')
  }
} catch (e) {
  console.log("error", e) // this shows the error message

  return e
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. It does not work. same console out put as above

Answer (score 0):

Use callback function instead of returning error(maybe it's not possible to return anything from redux actions)

```
// Login.js
async  handleSubmit(event) {
    let userLoginObject = {
      login: this.state.username,
      password: this.state.password,
    }
    if (!isEmptyOrNull(this.state.username) && !isEmptyOrNull(this.state.password)) 
    {
      let resp = await 
      this.props.onUserLogin(userLoginObject, error => {
         // Called when error is occurred
         this.setState({ formError: error }); 
      })
      console.log("resp",resp) 
      // this shows 'undefined'
      this.setState({ formError: resp }); //Im trying to set state to the formError
    }
}



// Action file
export const onUserLogin = (userLoginData, onError /** error callback */) => async (dispatch) => 
{
   const loginResponse = await doUserLogin(userLoginData)
   dispatch({
      type: ACTION_LOGIN,
      data: loginResponse,
  })
  if (loginResponse.token) {
      history.push('/investments')
  }
  else {
   console.log("err",loginResponse.error) // this shows the error message
    onError(loginResponse); // call callback function and send error with it
    return loginResponse
  }
}
```

Using Callback function

```
this.props.onUserLogin(userLoginObject, error => {
   // Called when error is occurred
   this.setState({ formError: error });
});
```

Comment: it says `onError(loginResponse.error); ` is not a function

Comment: You need to pass a function as a argument in calling function. Here onUserLogin action has two arguments one for data and other is callback function that is called when an error is occurred. You also need to pass the function while calling this action. Like this => `this.props.onUserLogin(userLoginObject, error => {
         // Called when error is occurred
         this.setState({ formError: resp }); 
      })`

Answer (score 0):

Since you are already using redux, I would recommend a different aproach what if, in your dispatch action you actually save the error message as a prop(if that is the case), and then show it in your component. instead of using

this.setState({ formError: resp });

you can recover the error from redux directly

this.props.errorLogin